# <type 'exceptions.NameError'>

Tags: python, mysql, web-applications, nameerror

Trying to create a web application (using mySQL and Python) with a list of hiking trails in MA. I just want to display all the names of trails in my DB on one page and cannot figure out why nothing will display:

```
################################################################################
def getAllHikes():
"""
This is a middleware function to read from the database.
It returns a list containing records of all trails we have in the table.
"""

# connect to db
conn, cursor = getConnectionAndCursor()

# prepare SQL
sql = """
SELECT name
FROM hiking
"""

# run the SQL
cursor.execute(sql)

# fetch the results
data = cursor.fetchall()

# clean up
cursor.close()
conn.close()

return data

################################################################################
def showAllHikes(data):
'''Produce a table showing all trails, one per row.'''

print('''
Here are all the popular trails we have on file:
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>%s</td>
      <td>%s</td>
      <td>%s</td>
      <td>%s</td>
      <td>%s</td>
    </tr>
      ''') % (name, town)

print('''
</table>
''')
################################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":

# get form field data
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

doHTMLHead("MassHike: A database of popular Massachusetts trails")

data = getAllHikes()
showAllHikes(data)


doHTMLTail()
```

I always encounter this problem when I try to work with web applications. I get an error saying **args = ("global name 'name' is not defined",)**

If you can explain in very simple terms I would appreciate it. I don't really understand this at all. Thanks!

Comment: What line is your error in? Is it the result of your SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is within the method below. You do not have `name` or `town` defined within the function or at the `global` level.

```
def showAllHikes(data):
    '''Produce a table showing all trails, one per row.'''

    print('''
    Here are all the popular trails we have on file:
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td>%s</td>
          <td>%s</td>
          <td>%s</td>
          <td>%s</td>
          <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
          ''') % (name, town)

    print('''
    </table>
    ''')
```

In order to get this information you will need to go through the `data` which according to [MySQL fetchall](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html) appears to be a `list` of `tuple`.

With this information we can do the following:

```
print('''
    Here are all the popular trails we have on file:
    <table>''')
for name, town in data:
    print('''
        <tr>
          <td>%s</td>
          <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
          ''') % (name, town)

print('''
    </table>
    ''')
```

However, it looks like your sql query needs to include the town information as it is currently only `sql = """SELECT name FROM hiking"""`, so this will more than likely fail with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```